# PHP Variable Scope understanding

Tags: php, variables, scope

Just started learning PHP, and while experimenting with **variable scopes**, I created this code:

```
<?php
    $x = 5;

    function scopeTest($x) {
        global $x;
        echo $x;            
    }

    scopeTest(4);
?>
```

In the given function I pass value `4`, in the function that value is stored in variable `$x` (local to the function). The output of this code is `5` and not `4`.

I don't know where the variable with value `4` gone? **I know I can do this by changing the local variable name** in the function but I want to know flow of this program, how it is outputting `5`.

Is the local variable `$x` overridden with the global variable `$x`?

Is there any way to access the local variable `$x` value `4` within the function?

Comment: One of the reasons why using `global` isn't a good idea.... this isn't intuitive behaviour

Comment: One way to be able to access both is to assign the `$x` argument to a different variable than the global `function scopeTest($y) {
        global $x;
        echo $x;  echo $y;            
    }
`

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, I've already written that thing in my question. I know that I can do that, but just wanted to know what happens really behind the scenes..

Comment: Another option would be to move the argument to another local scope variable ___before___ declaring the global: `function scopeTest($x) { $y = $x; global $x; echo $x; echo $y; }`.... it's only at the point in the function where you declare the `global $x` that the local `$x` argument gets overwridden

Comment: If the global variable `$x` doesn't exist, then PHP will happily create one for you, giving it a value of `null`! No warnings either ;-/

Comment: @RyanVincent - another reason why using `global` is a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variable is being overwritten with the statement `global` and since they are sharing the same variable name, you lost reference to it.

But by doing this, you can use both:

```
$x = 5;

function scopeTest($x) {
  echo $GLOBALS['x'], $x; // 54      
}

scopeTest(4);
```

Or.. just rename the local variable

```
function scopeTest($y) {
  global $x;
  echo $x, $y;           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can use the value 4 of the $x by echoing the $x before the global $x;

```
global $x; //replace the value of $x to it's global value.
```